# Poisson mesh reconstruction

Tags: meshlab

Using Meshlab ver. 1.3.3, I used to perform mesh reconstruction by using
**Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction** ► **Surface Reconstruction: Poisson**.

I have now installed Meshlab 2016, and Poisson reconstruction seems to have vanished...

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MeshLab 2016 now uses the new version of the Poisson merging, and the filter is called:

Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction

it is in the same submenu, on the bottom.
The relevant parameter (octree depth) is called Reconstruction Depth. 
It is now possible to merge multiple layers at once, without flattening them beforehand (as before). If source layer(s) have color, the result will be colored too. 
If you want to have the same result of the old version, put 0 in the "interpolation weight" parameter

Comment: They seem to have moved it for the current version.  Instead of the Poisson Reconstruction being found in Filters->Point Set.  It's now under Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction.